# Generic Function to fill a attribute of object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm creating a method `setParameter` in class `Manager` that should allow to user to fill out Object of type `Settings`.
After every update of settings I have to redraw scene.
The code I have now:

```
class Settings {
    a: number = 0;
    b: string = "xyz";
}

class Manager { 
    settings : Settings
    constructor() {}
    update(){...}
    setParameter<T keyof Settings>(name: T, data: any) {
        settings[name] = data;
        update();
    }
}
```

The question is:
Is there any way to somehow get the type of attribute `T` we got by `T keyof Settings`  and to avoid using`Any`??

I tried to use `any` but this is not perfect ad it does not give the user the hint that what type given parameter has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some type, `Obj` that represents an object literal type.

```
type Obj = {
  a:string;
  b:number;
}
```

You can get object keys as you've outline in the question, using `keyof`

```
type ObjKey = keyof Obj;
```

You can then get object type values by indexing the type with the key type.

```
type ObjValue = Obj[ObjKey]
```

In a generic context this is useful as you can preserve mapping between specific keys and values.

```
const setPropertyValue = <T extends keyof Obj>(key:T, value:Obj[T])=>{};
```

```
setPropertyValue('a','some string')
setPropertyValue('a',5) //error
setPropertyValue('b',4)
setPropertyValue('b','some string') //error
```

For your example, changing the `data` arg type to `Settings[T]` should work.

```
setParameter<T extends keyof Settings>(name: T, data: Settings[T])
```

The generic should use the extends keyword for the syntax to be correct

Answer (score 1):

1. We use a generic constraint T extends keyof Settings to ensure that T can only be a valid key of the Settings class.
2. We use Settings[T] to access the type of the property corresponding to the key T. This ensures that the data argument has the correct type based on the selected key.

```
class Settings {
    a: number = 0;
    b: string = "xyz";
}

class Manager {
    settings: Settings;

    constructor() {
        this.settings = new Settings();
    }

    update() {
        // Implement your update logic here
    }

    setParameter<T extends keyof Settings>(name: T, data: Settings[T]) {
        this.settings[name] = data;
        this.update();
    }
}
```